# How can I vertically align an asp:Label within a responsive div?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, .net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to align a label with a div that is responsive in size (bootstrap). I have tried the following code:

```
<div id="teamDivision" runat="server" class="col-sm-4 square" style="display:table-cell;float:left;text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; color:white; padding:0px !important;background-color:transparent;line-height:inherit !important;">
    <asp:Label class="info" id="division" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
</div>
```

This results in the label horizontally aligned center, but appears at the bottom of the div. I want it to always be horizontally and vertically centered.

Comment: Can you post the rendered html/css?

Comment: Do you mean a pic of what it looks like in browser?

Comment: no I mean the HTML and CSS that is generated from this code, and any relevant context. If I replace `<asp: Label>` with a random element, it doesn't reproduce the behavior you described in the post. We need a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.